# How to record the video output from FPV drone monitor with a laptop (video output from monitor is 3.5mm headphone jack)

Tags: video

I have recently built a small FPV drone. The drone can only lift around 100g off the ground, and only flies well with a payload less than 40g. The drone has a Runcam Robin camera, and transmits to a Hawkeye Little Pilot 3 monitor. There is a video output on the monitor, which is a 3.5mm headphone jack. What do I need to buy in order to record the video out of the monitor? How can I show this video on say, my laptop?

Answer (score 0):

If your drone provides an RTMP feed then you may be able to simply connect to the RTMP feed directly from your computer by using the drones RTPM URL and a player on your computer like VLC player.

If not and you want to use the output port on your monitor, then it sounds like you have a 3.5mm AV jack which you can likely connect to an external DVR using a 3.5mm AV jack to Phono conversion cable - something like this:

[image]

This is dependant on the output being in a standard format.